# VSCode Pylance: failing to recognize subtype of Pydantic StrictStr as str

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pydantic

I have the following code typed into a python file in VS Code.

```
from typing import Dict
from pydantic import StrictStr


class StrictStrSub(StrictStr):
    pass


def f(d: Dict[StrictStrSub, str]):
    e: Dict[str, str] = d


def h(d: Dict[StrictStr, str]):
    e: Dict[str, str] = d
```

VS Code identifies one problem with this file (red underline):
[image]

But it seems to me this is erroneous, due to the combination of

1. `StrictStr` does not have this error
2. `StrictStrSub` is a subclass of `StrictStr`.

Questions.

- Does anyone else observe this issue?
- Am I correct in saying this is an issue? If so, how should I resolve?

Comment: Probably a limitation of Pylance? I think you're right, since StrictStr is Annotated[str, Strict()] (see PEP for Annotated: https://peps.python.org/pep-0593/#rationale)

Comment: This has nothing to do with `StrictStr`. It is an issue with the fact that [`dict` is invariant](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types). You will see the same issue if make the keys inherit from `int` (for example).

Comment: That's not true @webelo, also in the example `h()` input dictionary accepts `StrictStr` as key, and PyLance doesn't complain - tried also myself locally

Comment: [`StrctStr` is simply an alias for `str`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/66369897d21138a645839a973f5e5b3ff7591ca1/pydantic/v1/types.py#L474) when type checking. That's why pylance doesn't complain about function `h`.

Comment: you're right, +1

Comment: I haven't encountered the same problem. I'm using `Pylance v2023.7.30` and `VSCode v1.80.1`.

Comment: @webelo is absolutely correct. This is basically the same issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765523/), only with `dict` instead of `list`.

Comment: Got it. Was not aware of the covariant, contravariant, invariant distinction. Thanks