# Python list[T] not assignable to list[T | None]

Tags: python, python-typing, pylance

I have a type `T`, a `namedtuple` actually:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

T = namedtuple('T', ('a', 'b'))
```

I have a function that accepts a `list[T | None]` and a list:

```py
def func(arg: list[T | None]):
    ...


l = [T(1, 2), T(2, 3)]
func(l)  # Pylance error
```

`l` is of type `list[T]`.

When I pass a `l` to the function I get an error from Pylance, that a `list[T]` is incompatible with `list[T | None]` because `T cannot be assigned to T | None`.

Aside from manually specifying my `list[T]` is actually a `list[T | None]`, what can I do to make this work without an error? Of course at runtime everything runs as expected.

Comment: Do you really mean "a list that contains either T's or None's"?  Or do you mean "a list that contains T's but might be empty"?

Comment: Please write an actual and complete [mre]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in mutable generic collection types such as `list` are all **invariant** in their type parameter. (see [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance))

This means that given a type `S` that is a subtype of `T`, `list[S]` is **not** a subtype (nor a supertype) of `list[T]`.

You can simplify your error even further:

```py
def f(a: list[int | None]) -> None: ...

b = [1, 2]
f(b)
```

`int` is obviously a subtype of `int | None`, but `list[int]` is not a subtype of `list[int | None]`.

For the code above, Mypy is so kind as to present additional info telling us exactly that:

```
error: Argument 1 to "f" has incompatible type "List[int]"; expected "List[Optional[int]]"  [arg-type]
note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
```

Aside from the obvious solution you mentioned of explicitly annotating your list as `list[T | None]` beforehand, maybe you could follow the advice from Mypy and instead change the type accepted by your function to something less specific that still offers the protocols you need, but also happens to be **covariant** in its type parameter, e.g. [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence):

```py
from collections import namedtuple
from collections.abc import Sequence

T = namedtuple('T', ('a', 'b'))


def f(a: Sequence[T | None]) -> None:
    pass


b = [T(1, 2), T(2, 3)]
f(b)
```

This should pass without errors.

---

**PS**:

You did not mention, what exactly your function is doing with that list, but the solution with an immutable type like `Sequence` will obviously not work, if you intend to *mutate* it inside the function.

Mutablity really *is* the issue here and the reason why `list` is declared to be invariant in the first place. The [Mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generics) offer a really nice explanation for this reasoning.

So while it is *technically* possible to for example define your own generic protocol with a covariant type variable that emulates the methods you need in that function, I am not sure that would be a good idea. Better to reconsider what you actually need from that function and what would be safe to call it with.

Comment: Mypy's tip was excellent, pylance did not offer the same tip. My function doesn't change the list (otherwise obviously it wouldn't be OK - the function can add a None to the list, which the caller will never expect). Thanks!